# How to update an item Paging library (without room)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I'm learning the Paging library so I've created a simple application that requests to a remote server and shows a list of notes(I don't want to save items in local database).
 
I've followed [this tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/8-steps-to-implement-paging-library-in-android-d02500f7fffe) and this [sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample). Everything works great but what if I want to update a single item on the list? For example, I want to update the title of a specific item in the list. After searching for a couple of hours I could not find a proper solution for updating an item on the list without using Room.
These are some questions I found but they didn't help me:

- [Updating a single item in a recylerview. I am using paging library and would like to update a single item/row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059100/updating-a-single-item-in-a-recylerview-i-am-using-paging-library-and-would-lik)
- [Update list items in PagingLibrary w/o using Room (Network only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010167/update-list-items-in-paginglibrary-w-o-using-room-network-only)
- [How to update a single item in a PagedListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972676/how-to-update-a-single-item-in-a-pagedlistadapter)

Can someone tell me it is possible to update an item on the list when using the Paging library without using the Room? If yes, how?

Comment: If you own the data on the remote server, you can simply update the required item (note) such that the update gets uploaded to the server and updated data is fetched and presented to the UI.

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan No it is not possible also I don't want to fetch data again for a simple updating.

Comment: @hosseinAmini Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @shahram_developer not, unfortunately, the only way is using Room DB